# Except homepage, the requested URL was not found on this server (AWS EC2 wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2

I host two **wordpress** on **AWS EC2** (say `site1` and `site2`). The `site1` works perfectly, but the `site2` can only access the homepage, for other pages, encountering the following error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /just-for-test/ was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at site2.com Port 80

Both of two sites have the same permission. The `site2` configure file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.conf` is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site2.com
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The content of `/etc/hosts` is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost  #this is for site1.com, 000-default.conf

xx.xx.xx.xx site2.com
```

BTW, while accessing `http://site2.com/wp-content/uploads/`, everything is normal.

> Index of /wp-content/uploads
>
> Name  Last modified   Size    Description
>
> Parent Directory          -
>
> 2015/ 2015-05-24 00:17    -
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at site2.com Port 80

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled the htaccess file via the Apache config and/or set up WP Permalinks in the Apache config?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang There is no .htaccess under site2. I copy .htaccess from site1 to site2 and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Giles Hunt and @kittykittybangbang, I add `.htaccess` to my website whose content is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check your htaccess files on each site and check that mod_rewrite is configured correctly for both sites.

Comment: You got the point. There is no `.htaccess` under `site2`. I copy `.htaccess` from `site1` to `site2` and it works.